# How to implement a custom ImageView in which I can recycle Bitmap after drawing it in view?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, android-custom-view, android-memory

I am trying to implement a custom ImageView in android with which I can recycle Bitmap after setting it in view. We can't recycle bitmap with default ImageView provided from Android. I have a scenario in my application which is memory intensive and I'm trying to save memory as much as I can.

Can anyone guide me how to implement a custom ImageView with above feature?

Comment: why writing a custom view for this? Just use Glide. It uses in-memory cache, above all the other cache mechanisms. Check this link: https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html

Comment: @GregorioPalamà Thanks for suggestion but I can't use any library due to application size constraint. I need to implement this in my own code.

Comment: then you'll have to implement your own in-memory cache. Android SDK already provides something: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/cache-bitmap this should be useful for your needs

Comment: You're not really going to be able to do this.  So what happens when your view needs to redraw for any reason?  It doesn't have a reference to the Bitmap, so when it tries to draw it will either crash or do nothing.  Or need to reload the Bitmap at the worst time for performance.  There's a reason why ImageView keeps the reference around.

Comment: @GabeSechan I have this point in my mind. I will be designing it such a way that a single bitmap will be shared between multiple ImageViews. So, when onDraw() will be called, I will assure in my code that it gets a reference of bitmap.

Comment: But if you're doing that, you may as well just use image view, and give the same bitmap object to all of them